# Relationship between electric field lines and permitivities of media

Tags: electrostatics

Some books define (although some do not) the electric field flux as the number of electric field lines passing through a given area. Suppose that there is a electric filed created by a charge plate and the filed lines emerging from the plate are passing through two adjacent media having two different permitivities. In this case, the electric fields observed in two media should be different due to the differences in electric permitivities. So when the electric filed line model is applied here, which tells something about the field strength, we see that number of filed lines in two media are different. Does this mean that electric filed lines are created or destroy at the interface between media? I know obviously this is not the case, but how can we explain this situation? Should we apply the electric flux model separately to two media considering them individually?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a property of the madia